# pandas - change value in column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe `all_data` such as this:

```
Id  Zone        Neighb
1   NaN         IDOTRR
2   RL          Veenker
3   NaN         IDOTRR
4   RM          Crawfor
5   NaN         Mitchel
```

I want to input the missing values in 'Zone' column, such that where 'Neighb' is 'IDOTRR' I set 'Zone' to be 'RM', while where 'Neighb' is 'Mitchel' I set 'RL'.

```
all_data.loc[all_data.MSZoning.isnull() 
             & all_data.Neighborhood == "IDOTRR", "MSZoning"] = "RM"
all_data.loc[all_data.MSZoning.isnull() 
             & all_data.Neighborhood == "Mitchel", "MSZoning"] = "RL"
```

I get:

> TypeError: invalid type comparison
>
> C:\Users\pprun\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:798:
>   FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar
>   instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
>   result = getattr(x, name)(y)

I'm sure this is supposed to be simple but I've been messing around with it for too long already. Please help.

Comment: Try enclosing the tests in parentheses: `(all_data.MSZoning.isnull() )
             & (all_data.Neighborhood == "IDOTRR")`

Comment: @Acccumulation, THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, `&` takes precedence over `==`

http://www.annedawson.net/Python_Precedence.htm

So when you do `all_data.MSZoning.isnull() & all_data.Neighborhood == "Mitchel"`, that's interpreted as `(all_data.MSZoning.isnull() & all_data.Neighborhood) == "Mitchel"`, and now Python tries to `AND` a boolean Series with a str Series, and see whether it's equal to a single str `"Mitchel"`. The solution is to enclose the tests in parentheses: `(all_data.MSZoning.isnull()) & (all_data.Neighborhood == "Mitchel")`. Sometimes if I have a lot of selectors, I'll assign them to variables, and then `AND` them, e.g.:

```
null_zoning = all_data.MSZoning.isnull()
Mitchel_neighb = all_data.Neighborhood == "Mitchel"
all_data.loc[null_zoning & Mitchel_neighb, "MSZoning"] = "RL"
```

Not only does this take care of the order of operations issue, it also means that `all_data.loc[null_zoning & Mitchel_neighb, "MSZoning"] = "RL"` fits on one line.

Answer (score 3):

Use np.select i.e

```
df['Zone'] = np.select([df['Neighb'] == 'IDOTRR',df['Neighb'] == 'Mitchel'],['RM','RL'],df['Zone'])
```

```
   Id Zone   Neighb
0   1   RM   IDOTRR
1   2   RL  Veenker
2   3   RM   IDOTRR
3   4   RM  Crawfor
4   5   RL  Mitchel
```

In your case of condtions you can use

```
# Boolean mask of condition 1 
m1 = (all_data.MSZoning.isnull()) & (all_data.Neighborhood == "IDOTRR")
# Boolean mask of condition 2
m2 = (all_data.MSZoning.isnull()) & (all_data.Neighborhood == "Mitchel")

np.select([m1,m2],['RM','RL'],all_data["MSZoning"])
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's working perfectly. But, is it not possible to use `.loc` for the same purpose?

Comment: .loc makes things complicated so I used np.select which is faster and efficient. If you have more conditions let me know. I will update

Answer (score 2):

```
df.Zone=df.Zone.fillna(df.Neighb.replace({'IDOTRR':'RM','Mitchel':'RL'}))
df
Out[784]: 
   Id Zone   Neighb
0   1   RM   IDOTRR
1   2   RL  Veenker
2   3   RM   IDOTRR
3   4   RM  Crawfor
4   5   RL  Mitchel
```

Comment: Thats out of box thinking and does what OP is looking for +1.